# Site level search feature is not working in sharepoint,after a full crwal

Tags: sharepoint

I am having site level search in my share point site,its not working, I have done full crawl of database still its not working.Even I had configured search services again.Still its not working,whereas item level search is working.

Comment: Pl add code examples or any relevant examples on what you've tried so far and what works and what doesn't.

Comment: In [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1813/sharepoint-search-service-is-not-working) there are some tips about troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to perform following steps.

1. Make sure the search account has “full read” permissions in the web 
   applications
2. Entered my content sources and verified they are being crawled
3. Checked the crawling error log and there are no “Top Level Errors”
4. The search managed account has “SPSearchDBAdmin” rights in all 4 of
   the search databases
5. I have performed an “index Reset” and performed a full crawl
6. I have not disabled loop back check cause, according to my research
   this should not be done in production servers

Comment: Thanks @Mr. Roshan. Got it.